# undefined method [] for nil:NilClass in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have an hash consisting of:

```
flow = ["a", "b", "c"]
h = [{"case_id"=>1, "a"=>{"x"=>"text", "option"=>"..." },"b"=>{"report"=>"text", "option"=>"..." } ,"c"=>{"y"=>"text", "option"=>"..." }},{"case_id"=>2, "a"=>{"x"=>"text", "option"=>"..." },"b"=>{"report"=>"text", "option"=>"..." } ,"c"=>{"y"=>"text", "option"=>"..." }}]
@case = 0
@report = ""
flow.each do |step|
  if h[@case][step]['report']
    @report = h[@case][step]['report']
  end
end
```

the console gives me the following error:

```
NoMethodError in MainController#index
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Why?! In a previous program, but using ruby 187, gave no problem. But now, with ruby ​​193, gives this error.

Comment: there are two commas before c in `h` `, ,"c"`

Comment: is not that the error, write error. Sorry

Comment: Since the code looks OK, I would assume the error happens somewhere else in your code. Would you mind expanding on what else is done in the code around that part, and what the "something" part is doing?

Comment: I changed the code and added that 'something'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flow = ["a", "b", "c"]
h = { "a"=>{"x"=>"text", "option"=>"..." },"b"=>{"report"=>"text", "option"=>"..." } ,"c"=>{"y"=>"text", "option"=>"..." }}
flow.each do |f|
  if h[f]['report']
    #something
  end
end
```

Ruby has some great iteration helper provided by enumeration class

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: No, you wait to rewrite the code. Thanks anyway for the help you are giving me ;)

Comment: @SimoneMazzotta, try copy paste whole code in irb and check if it runs.

Comment: there are diff ways of debugging the code first get the exact line where error occurs use debuggers or simply put line no after each line `puts lineno` and check where the error occurs.

Comment: I found the problem, there was a 'd' in flow that there was no in h. trivial mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

You will not get error till either `h` or `h[a]` is `nil`. Please update your question properly.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?